# Lift: create AJAX hyperlink for each item with CSS transform

Tags: ajax, scala, lift

I want to create a list of items and have a hyperlink on each of them that performs some action, e.g. remove the item from the list.

My template looks like this:

```html
<lift:surround with="default" at="content">
<div class="locations lift:Main.locations">
    <ul>
        <li class="one">
            <span class="name">Neverland</span>
            (<a href="#" class="delete">delete this</a>)
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</lift:surround>
```

I'm using the following CSS transform to fill it out:

```scala
def locations = {
    ".one *" #> somecollection map { item =>
        ".name" #> item.name &
        ".delete" #> ????
    }
}
```

Now, instead of "????", I'd love to put in something along the lines of `SHtml.a( ()=>delete(item), _)`, but `_` here is of type `CssSel` and `a`'s argument should be `NodeSeq`

I could of course put simple `xml.Text("delete this")`, but I want to reuse the text that is inside the template.

Or is there a different way to generate AJAX hyperlinks?

Comment: You should add this as a proper answer and then accept it. That way the question appears solved to everybody.

Comment: i couldn't do that because my rep is too low, i had to wait until morning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do it. Basically, instead of generating the `a` tag, I have to use the tag from the template and put the AJAX code in it through the CSS transform:

```scala
def locations = {
    ".one *" # somecollection map { item =>
        ".name" #> item.name &
        ".delete [onclick]" #> ajaxInvoke (() => delete(item))
    }
}
```

I suspect that this way it would also be possible to make links that work both with and without JavaScript